# update of Date Textbox with calendar extender in gridview

Tags: javascript, ajax, date, gridview, calendar

Please friends help me out. I am trying to update a date column in my sql database. If i do it manually in edit mode in gridview it updates but when i use template field and attach ajax calendar extender it does not update but inserts null date into the database and eventually disappears from the gridview. Below is my code:
                        
                         <%#Eval("HandoverDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>

```
                 <EditItemTemplate>

                  <asp:TextBox ID="tbxDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("HandoverDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                     <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="tbxDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="tbxDate_CalendarExtender" TargetControlID="tbxDate" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You might consider creating a [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RobG- I have minified it.